# customize woocommerce templates and display store on home

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm making some changes to a custom template for a website that wants to add the woocommerce support to create a little shop. 
I've followed the instruction to add the theme support to the theme, in my function file I have added:

```
add_theme_support('woocommerce');
```

and the relative hook `after_setup_theme`. I'm not experienced with this plugin, it's the first time I'm using it and I'm still reading the docs. Can anyone explain to me how I can customize the woocommerce templates to use bootstrap 4 and how I can display the products or the store pages on the index of my theme? will the `get_template_part('woocommerce/template-name')` work or there are some particular procedure to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow This and Make sure Your Shop or which page you want for default Home page and Then Save Button.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change your "reading Settings" in Settings menu,

Please select "Your home page displays"  = check to a static page and select shop from the dropdown menu.

after these changes your index page will be shop page.